# How can I remove the eye from a password field?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10

I am not able to remove password eye from IE 10.
I tried using

```
input[password]::-ms-reveal {display : none ;}
```

but doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Clear and reavel password icons from IE10 (::-ms-clear, ::ms-reveal not working)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000562/removing-clear-and-reavel-password-icons-from-ie10-ms-clear-ms-reveal-not)

Comment: As shown in the duplicate, you don't need the element selector, just the pseudo selector. If you do want to use the element selector, it should be `input[type=password]:-ms-reveal { display: none; }`

Comment: it still won't work .

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Fashn/)

Comment: Works when no selector used .Thanks :)

Comment: Had a typo in my comment, it's missing the second `:`.

Comment: It's working in ie-10  but not previous versions. Please help me how to prevent these in previous versions also.

Comment: Whilst this is possible with the answer below, I'd warn against removing platform specific features from a UX standpoint.  Hiding the eye icon offers no advantage to your users, and those on Windows 8+ will **expect** it.

Comment: Is there a similar solution available for Safari?

Answer (score 39):

This one works just fine:

```
input[type=password]::-ms-reveal,
input[type=password]::-ms-clear
{
    display: none;
}
```