# Html/CSS: How to make the Password Visible Button Re-appear

Tags: html, css, passwords

after i entered my password and move to other field but if i clicked again on password field the password reveling button won't show up.

I am a beginner and don't know much about it. I'm expecting someone can solve my issue with some explanation.

HTML:

```
    <div class="pass">
    <label for="myPass">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="myPass" id="myPass" 
    placeholder="Enter your Password" required>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.pass ::placeholder{
    text-align: center;
}

#myPass {
    width: 15rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-color: #725E54;
}
```

Comment: For starters as you are a beginner please put some code with your question to show that 'this is the code where i am facing the trouble' no one can help you just by reading what you have written now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay; the property that you are referring to is ::-ms-reveal it controls the "show password reveal button at the edge input for type password" but the catch is it is only supported by edge and IE

| Feature | Firefox (Gecko) | Chrome | Internet Explorer | Opera | Safari | Firefox Mobile (Gecko) | Android | IE Phone | Opera Mobile | Safari Mobile |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Basic support | No support | No support | (Yes) | No support | No support | No support | No support | (Yes) | No support | No support |
| Basic support | No support | No support | (Yes) | No support | No support | No support | No support | (Yes) | No support | No support |

But it's implementation is not that tough, do comment if you need help with that, you just need to convert input type to text on show and back to password on hidden

Comment: Thank you for your response Sir! I'm using checkbox for this case because i found out that  **This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.** from @Deepak-MSFT [posted this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61450596/23087750).

Comment: @hm_intresting.. yup only for edge it is supported; its implementation is easy, if u want to have an eye icon, giving you steps:
use icon inside the input box (use before or after), have a js event on it

Comment: @SarimAhmed strictly, you can't have ::before/after pseudo elements on an input element.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, I can't use eye icon in the input field as flexibly as button to act as toggle between text and password. you can check [how button act as toggle to show password and text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43391967/23087750)